# How to prove that $R^n\setminus \{0\}$ is not contractible

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, geometric-topology

If I must prove that $R^{n}\setminus\{0\}$ is not contractible, how may I do so formally. Using the intuitive notion of contractibility at a point as being that any surface homeomorphic to an $n$ sphere, I was thinking that it could be proven by contradiction as follows:
Assume for the sake of contradiction that $R^{n}\setminus\{0\}$ is contractible. Then, as $R^{n}\setminus\{0\}$ can be continuously mapped to $S^{n-1}$, $S^{n-1}$ must also be contractible. However, as the only shape homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}$ that passes through the point under consideration is $S^{n-1}$ itself, there exists no contraction at that point of an $S^{n-1}$ sphere to a point. Thus, we have reached a contradiction, and  $R^{n}\setminus\{0\}$ is not contractible.
If indeed the formal definition of contractibility (in terms of null homotopy)is equivalent to the one I have used, could you please tell me a source for the same? (so that I may cite it for an assignment)

Comment: you said " $\mathbf{R}^n/ \{0\}$ can be continuously mapped to $S^{n-1}$", Is it  $\mathbf{R}^n/ \{0\}$ or $\mathbf{R}^n-\{0\}$?

Comment: When you write "as $R^n \setminus \{0\}$ can be continuously mapped to $S^{n-1}$", you have to write "as $R^n \setminus \{0\}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-1}$". If you have a continous map from $X$ to $Y$ and $X$ is contractible, $Y$ does not need to be contractible. For example, the inclusion $\{N\} \hookrightarrow S^1$ of the north-pole to the circle is continous and $\{N\}$ is contractible, but $S^1$ is not.

Comment: If it is $\mathbf{R}^n -\{0\}$, homotopy equivalent does the job. If Contractible, $S^{n-1} \sim\mathbf{R}^n -\{0\}\sim * $. Contradiction

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3061415/proof-regarding-n-conectedness) question of the user: We are really talking about $R^n \setminus \{0\}$, not $R^n/\{0\}$, which would be $R^n$ anyway.

Comment: Sorry for the notational error. I did mean $R^{n}-\{0\}$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with a "shape homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}$ that passes through the point of consideration". Neither do I really understand your "informal" definition of contractability. I think it would also help if you could state the definition of contracibility you know.

Comment: The definition of contractibility that I am currently assuming is based upon the idea that contractibility is an extension of simple connectedness (as explained in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) wikipedia article under the heading of informal discussion).  My definition is that a space of $n$ dimensions is contractible if and only if there exists a homotopy between any "loop" of $n$ dimensions within that space(i.e. a space that is homeomorphic to an $n$-sphere) and all the points on that loop.

Comment: Additionally,could you tell me under what conditions (When $X$ is contractible) the existence of a continuous map from $X$ to $Y$ implies  that $Y$ is contractible. P.S. I'm sorry for the troubles that my lack of clarity may have caused.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your property that every $n$-dimensional loop in $X$ can be contracted means that $\pi_n(X) \cong 0$. If all homotopy groups $\pi_n(X)$ are trivial, $X$ is called *[weakly contractible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_contractible)*. In general, this is weaker than being contractible. If $X$ is CW (and your examples are even manifolds), the two properties coincide.

Comment: Im sorry, but my reputation is not high enough to chat yet. Could you initiate chatting instead, @Babelfish ?

Comment: [I tried to open chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87831/how-to-prove-that-rn0-is-not-contractible)

Comment: Could you upvote so that my reputation becomes 20?